# The new tag list in the 10k tools miscounts when added tag edits are rolled back

Tags: bug, tags, 10k-tools, rollbacks

Today someone created [mysql-process](/questions/tagged/mysql-process) for the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command.  The [processlist](/questions/tagged/processlist) tag already covers that subject.  The person that created the new tag also added it to four questions other than his own.  Hilariously, all but one of those edited questions already had the older tag.

Normally I edit these things out, but for some reason I rolled back the edits instead.

The tag remained in the 10k tools new tag list as having four questions until it was automatically removed from the system for being an empty tag.  In reality, it had none, but it did previously exist in four places where the edit that added it was rolled back.  The fifth place was the creator's question, which was edited instead of rolled back.

---

Just did the same for [interview-questions](/questions/tagged/interview-questions).  I rolled back [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192219/simple-delegate-delegate-vs-multicast-delegates), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732864/finalize-vs-dispose), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516148/why-cant-i-have-protected-interface-members) instances, and the tag still shows up in the 10k new tags list... interestingly as having two questions, not three.  Puzzling.  Maybe it is just (aggressive) caching?

Comment: Caching? *character limit*

Comment: I did the reverts 13 hours ago, and I did the last change on the original question that added the tag, so in theory if it was doing a *recount* every time it should have noticed.  I doubt it's *normal* caching.  Denormalization?

Comment: Denormalisation is just a type of caching. *(this comment is not intended to be technically accurate)*